# $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

**Problem**: $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

**Solution**: Let $F=\Bbb{Q}$ be a field of rational numbers and take $p(x)=x^2-2$, irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ By **Eisenstein's Criterion**.

Define a map $\psi:F\to {F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}$ by $\psi(a)=a+\left<x^2-2\right>$, for $a\in F$.

This map makes sense. because $\left<x^2-2\right>$ is irreducible over $F$. Thus $\left<x^2-2\right>$ is a maximal ideal. Therefore ,${F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}$ is a field.
Clearly $\psi$ is injective ring homomorphism. Therefore, ${F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}$ is a field extension of $F$. Of course I know that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$.

Is it enough to show that for extension?

Comment: Well, $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ is a field, and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\supseteq\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I know. Is this solution correct?

Comment: Hmm, this is enough, that homomorphism proves $\mathbb{Q} $ has an isomorphic image in the field $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] $ , that indicates towards field extension theory.

Comment: That I know . Yes. Because by $1^{st}$ isomorphism theorem, $\psi(F)$ is isomorphic to $F/\operatorname{ker}\psi=F$. This $\psi(F)$ is a subfield of $F[x]/<x^2-2>$. That is isomorphic to $F$. Previous comment had some typo error.

Comment: No issues, except please mention that you already know that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x] / \langle x^2- 2\rangle$

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Ok. I'll mention that. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Now, what do we do about an answer to this question?

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон s Now we define a function $\psi : \Bbb{Q}( \sqrt{ 2})\to \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x ^2 −2)$ by letting $\psi(a + b \sqrt{2}) = [a + bx]$ for any $a, b \in \Bbb{ Q}$. We show that $\psi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @AmanPandey I understood that. I am saying that we need to close this question by accepting an answer written below. I am suggesting that you answer the question and accept it after some time. Take your answer from the comments and from your question post.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Yes before doing this . Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you do it from the definition of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$? Basically show that every element of that has a multiplicative inverse? The definition of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is all rational functions in $\sqrt 2$, right? (Or, the smallest field containing $\sqrt 2$ and $\mathbb Q$, but that is obsolete for our purpose).

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон yes. I can show that.

Comment: Ok, so that is a second method. Put both methods below as an answer, I would say.

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон ok Sir! Very thanks to you!

Comment: Sure, but don't call me sir (see my profile)

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Ok mam. Well! This is a very long name. I mostly heard this name from south Indians. 'Sarvesh' is a male name. That's why i confused. Any way. Thanks:)

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111668/discussion-between-aman-pandey-and----).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847246/469000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this answer because it answers also two to three questions. It would be helpful for others who looks answers like$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$.

Let $F=\Bbb{Q}$ be a field of rational numbers and take $p(x)=x^2-2$, irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ By **Eisenstein's Criterion**.

Define a map $\psi:F\to {F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}$ by $\psi(a)=a+\left<x^2-2\right>$, for $a\in F$.

This map makes sense because $\left<x^2-2\right>$ is irreducible over $F$. Thus $\left<x^2-2\right>$ is a maximal ideal. Therefore ,${F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}$ is a field.
Clearly $\psi$ is injective ring homomorphism. If we'll show that ${F[x]}/{\left<x^2-2\right>}\cong F$. Then $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

So first we will show  that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$.

Define a map $\psi:\Bbb{Q}\sqrt{2}\to \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$ by $\psi(a+b\sqrt{2})=[a+bx]$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb{Q}$.

$\psi$ is homomorphism:

$\psi((a+b\sqrt{2})+(c+d\sqrt{2}))=\psi((a+c)+(b+d)\sqrt{2}))=[(a+c)+(b+d)x]=[a+bx]+[c+dx]=\psi(a+b\sqrt{2})+\psi(c+d\sqrt{2}$.

$\psi((a+b\sqrt{2})(c+d\sqrt{2})=\psi((ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)\sqrt{2}))=[(ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)x]$.
and,
$\psi((a+b\sqrt{2})\psi(c+d\sqrt{2})=[a+bx][c+dx]=[ac+adx+bcx+bdx^2]=[ac+(ad+bc)x+bdx^2]=[(ac+2bd)+(ad+bc)x]$.

Therefore, $\psi$ is homomorphism.

$\psi$ is injective:

Let, $\psi(a + b\sqrt{2}) = \psi(c + d\sqrt{2})$, then $[a + bx] = [c + dx]$. Since there is a
unique polynomial of degree $1$ or less for each congruence class $\operatorname{mod} p(x)$.
$\Rightarrow$  $a + bx = c + dx$ $\Rightarrow$ $ a = c$ and $b = d$. Hence $\psi$ is injective.

$\psi$ is surjective:

Let $y\in \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$ then $y=[l+mx]$ for some $l,m\in \Bbb{Q}$. Therefore $\psi(l+m\sqrt{2})=y=[l+mx]$.

$\Rightarrow$  $\psi$ is surjective.
And hence $\psi$ is isomorphism. Thus $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\cong \Bbb{Q}[x]/<x^2-2>$. Thus $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is extension of $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, for me that is good enough!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept this answer once you are allowed to. +1

Comment: @TeresaLisbon After 2days I'll be able to accept this answer.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Please have a look to this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3789565/469000

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I need some help regarding study. May i have your email address if you don't mind or I should put my email address in comment box.  Please feel free to comment. Thanks!

Comment: My email address is sarveshiyer@gmail.com  (My name is Sarvesh (names of father, grandfathers and great grandfathers) Iyer) , @AmanPandey. I don't actually visit this very often. You  can definitely send mails here, but I prefer it if you send like one mail a day for clarifications. Also, sometimes I may not be able to answer your question but just comment on it, so you may be a little dissatisfied. Continue to post on MSE for your general doubts and queries like the one above. What study are you preparing for, out of curiosity?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I am doing masters(in maths) currently and it will end by July. So I am confused, for phd which topic should I choose? I like both abstract algebra and General topology. Also, I would like to know whether you live in India, if yes, then you can help for my phd, what should I do for phd....like that.

Comment: I work in probability. Without doubt you should be attempting for the institutes in Chennai, namely CMI and IMSc, if you are interested in those topics. For the purpose of PhD admission, sign up for the NBHM exam quickly, which is the way to get into IMSc. Do well in the interview and you are set! Also the CMI exam will be there in May. You can try the IITs and IISc, they will also take PhDs from NBHM and so on, if I am not wrong. You are from Central Univ. of Haryana : closer to (your) home, IIT Delhi and ISI Delhi are great options(contd..).

Comment: On the topic of a PhD, note that you should be really well read if you are looking at algebraic topology/geometry. There is too much background to get over , before you can hit the research track. On the other hand, general topology is almost non-existent in India, so you should be looking at one of algebraic topology/geometry. (There's a joke, everyone who talks to me instantaneously develops a non-zero probability of moving into probability!)  Begin with the classical texts of Hatcher and so on. Also gauge your interest in analysis, there are cross topics like manifolds you might like.(cont)

Comment: Finally, I am in India, and therefore there's no worry of my time zone being off!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon you are right! I am from CUH. I applied for 'Gate' and 'Tifr'. Due to home exam, I am not able to give enough time for those upcoming competitions. But, I'll manage. Whenever I need you I'll. Actually I can't post some problems on MSE sometimes problems  are very stupid.

Comment: You are welcome to do so, Aman. Thanks for contacting me. (Note : I will not reply further, back to work for me!)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much for your valuable time!