# Prove that $F(\alpha)\cong F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))$.

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification, extension-field

There is a natural homomorphism

$$\phi:F[x]\to F(\alpha)$$

$$\phi(p(x))=p(\alpha)$$

obtained by a mapping which leaves coefficient of polynomial unchanged and sends $x$ to $\alpha$.

Clearly $m_\alpha(x)\in \operatorname{ker}\phi$. Where $\operatorname{ker}\phi=\{p(x)\in F[x]:p(\alpha)=0\}$. So we obtain an induced homomorphism:

$$\phi:F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))\to F(\alpha).$$

$F[x]$ is P.I.D. which is generated by unique monic polynomial $m_\alpha(x)$.  which is irreducible since the homomorphism $\phi$ is a surjection onto the field $F(\alpha)$.

Therefore $F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))$ is a field. the map $\phi$ is not the zero map . 
Therefore , $\phi$ is injective ring homomorphism. By the definition of $F(\alpha)$ the map $\phi$ must be surjective.

It follows that $\phi$ is isomorphism. Hence $F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))\cong F(\alpha)$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Hi you called me here. I had a look, and I think the question is good and Bernard has done a good job below. +1

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thanks Lisbon! Is my proof correct?

Comment: I gave the +1 because I thought it was fine

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Ahh! Thank you:)

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Please have a look to my answer. Actually I had a problem with minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all we prove a lemma then we prove the main theorem**

**Lemma:** Let $L/K$ is a field extension. Let $\alpha\in L$ is algebraic over $K$. Then the minimal polynomial in $\alpha$ over $K$ is unique and irreducible.

**Proof:** let $m_\alpha(x)$ be a minimal polynomial with degree $n$. By the uniqueness of minimal polynomial we have that $m_\alpha(x)$ is unique minimal polynomial.
Let us assume that leading coefficient of $m_\alpha(x)$ is $1$ (because $K$ is a field).
Assuming the contrary. Suppose $m_\alpha(x)$ is reducible.
Then there exist non-constant polynomial $g(x),h(x)\in K[x]$ such that: $m_\alpha(x)=g(x)h(x).$
$\Rightarrow$ $g(\alpha)h(\alpha)=0$. Then either $h(\alpha)=0$ or $g(\alpha)=0$(Since $L$ is an integral domain).
contradict the minimality of $m_\alpha(x)$.

**Proof of the main theorem**

**Proof:** There is a natural homomorphism

$$\phi:F[x]\to F(\alpha)$$

$$\phi(p(x))=p(\alpha)$$

obtained by a mapping which leaves coefficient of polynomial unchanged and sends $x$ to $\alpha$.

Clearly $m_\alpha(x)\in \operatorname{ker}\phi$. Where $\operatorname{ker}\phi=\{p(x)\in F[x]:p(\alpha)=0\}$. So we obtain an induced homomorphism:

$$\phi:F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))\to F(\alpha).$$
$\alpha\in F(\alpha)$ is algebraic over $F$. Then the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha(x)$ over $F$ is unique and irreducible polynomial(**By above Lemma**).
Therefore $F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))$ is a field. the map $\phi$ is not the zero map . 
Therefore , $\phi$ is injective ring homomorphism. Since $\operatorname{Im}\phi$ is isomorphic to its image which is a subfield of $F(\alpha)$(By **$1^{st}$ isomorphosm theorem)**. By the definition of $F(\alpha)$ the map $\phi$ must be surjective.
 It follows that $\phi$ is isomorphism. Hence $F[x]/(m_\alpha(x))\cong F(\alpha)$

Comment: Your proof that $m_{\alpha}$ is irreducible seems fine.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The homomorphism $\psi$ is defined in a confusing way. Actually, it is defined as follows: for any polynomial $p(X)\in F[X]$, we set $$\psi(p(X)))=p(\alpha)$$
which amounts to defines the image of the indeterminate $X$ as $X\mapsto\alpha$.

Now $\,\ker\psi=\{p(X)\in F[X]\mid p(\alpha)=0\}$, i.e. the ideal  of polynomials which have $\alpha$ as a root. As $F[X]$ is a P.I.D., it is generated by a unique minimal polynomial, which is irreducible since the homomorphism $\psi$ is a *surjection onto the field* $F[\alpha]$.

Comment: Is it about notation? I didn't mention but my intuition is same I mean for any polynomial $a(x)\in F[X]$, set $\psi(a(x))=a(\alpha)$ and $x$ sends $a$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, but $a$ does not send $x$ (or rather $X$) anywhere. A polynomial is not a function (and that's why we use the capital $X$ to denote the indeterminate). It is $\psi$ which maps $X$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: If I just remove **send** word and use what you used. Then my proof will be completely ok??

Comment: Also, $\psi$ has nothing to do with the identity mapping, since the domain and codomain are different. I guess I see what you meant: that $\psi$ leaves the coefficients of polynomials unchanged, simply substitutes $\alpha$ to the indeterminate.

Comment: exactly! please see my recent edits. Is the proof Ok now?

Comment: Almost. You should mention the first isomorphism theorem. The generating monic polynomial is irreducible, not only because $F[X]$ is a P.I.D., but also because the image $F[\alpha]$ is a field ($\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is not necessarily generated by a prime element, albeit $\mathbf Z$ is a P.I.D.)

Comment: Thanks${}{}{}$!